# SCOM 2012 - JBoss / MBeans

Tags: scom

Recently i have started getting familiar with SCOM 2012 because my company is thinking to change to SCOM from RHQ.

So, for testing purposes i have installed SCOM Server on a machine.
I want to monitor a JBoss application server which i have on an another machine. This application server has a application running on it.

What I've done so far, is that have discovered manually the machine of the application server by using those Powershell scripts, have deployed BeanSpy on the application server (the BeanSpy.HTTP.NoAuth.ear and renamed it to BeanSpy.ear since my app server uses no authentication).

I can see my app server on the Monitoring menu on the Operation Manager, under the Java Monitoring -> JEE Application Servers ->  JBoss Application Servers, and the applications that are on it under Applications sub-menu.

Also i can see it under the Deep Monitored Configurations sub-menu, but i don't see it under the Configurations sub-menu.

So my first question is why isn't my application server or the machine in the Configurations sub-menu

My second question is, how can i see on the Operation Manger the information from the MBeans. I know that MBeans are accessed through BeanSpy, but i don't understand how to get this information or where to find it on SCOM.

If anyone has good knowledge on SCOM, please reply me back. I am just trying to understand it since i am new to this.

I have read the official doc of SCOM but i am also looking for some additional help to understand it even better.

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about JEE or JBoss, but I found a couple TechNet articles that may be helpful. It looks like there aren't out-of-the-box monitoring packs, so you'll have to develop something yourself.  Check the articles out.  I hope they at least get you pointed in the right direction.

[Howto: Monitor EJBs with BeanSpy in SCOM 2012 on JBoss 5](http://blogs.technet.com/b/random_happy_dev_thoughts/archive/2013/01/25/howto-monitor-ejbs-with-beanspy-in-scom-2012.aspx)

[Manually Discovering JEE Application Servers with SCOM 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/random_happy_dev_thoughts/archive/2012/05/21/manually-discovering-jee-application-servers-with-scom-2012.aspx)

If not, you could always set up your own monitors to monitor processes, web sites / services, or logs and generate alerts based on those.

Good luck